# One hot encoding variable n m mode numbers

Tags: one-hot-encoding

I'm doing image classification of with image labels of mode numbers `m` and `n`. I'm also varying the convnet training to take in different maximum mode numbers to test it out, before fully training on a massive data set.

Silly question but, given a label `(m,n)` how do I one hot encode it into an array of length `n*m`?

Thanks.

Edit: Yikes this is actually really simple,

```
modenum = %some integer
def getLabel(n,m):
    array = np.zeros((modeNum,modeNum),dtype='int8')
    array[n,m] = 1
    label = np.ndarray.flatten(array)
    return label
```